# Game View disappears when moved from one tab to another

Tags: ios, xamarin, cocossharp

I have 2 tabs and on the view I have a game view. As I move from one tab to another, the game view disappears. `ViewDidDisappear` method is called. How to resolve this?

```
public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated) { 
    base.ViewWillAppear(animated); 
    if (gameView != null) { 
        gameScene = new CCScene(gameView); 
        gameScene.AddLayer(new GameLayer()); 
        if (gameView.Director.RunningScene != null) { 
            gameView.Director.PopScene(); 
        } 
        gameView.RunWithScene(gameScene); 
    } 
}   

public override void ViewDidDisappear(bool animated) { 
    if (gameView != null) { 
        gameView.Paused = true; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Shreya could you please share your code? or any screen shot? Your problem is not 100% undestandable

Comment: put the code which you have tryed

Comment: public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
  {
   base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
   if (gameView != null)
   {
    gameScene = new CCScene(gameView);
    gameScene.AddLayer(new GameLayer());
    if (gameView.Director.RunningScene != null)
    {
     gameView.Director.PopScene();
    }
    gameView.RunWithScene(gameScene);
   }

  }

Comment: public override void ViewDidDisappear(bool animated)
  {

   if (gameView != null)
   {
    gameView.Paused = true;
   }

   
  }

Comment: in my storyboard, on the view i have a game view and a tab bar containing 2 tabs. As i switch to second tab and then to the first tab, the game view on the first tab disappears.

Comment: @ShreyaKarnawat You may want consolidate info by editing your original post to include the code & details rather than putting it in the comments. Here are some [tips](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help.

Comment: if you move to another tab the tab with games disappears  and viewdiddisappear method is called. What exactly you need to fix?

Comment: I dont want that when i move to another tab and when come back to the previous tab, the game view should disappear